# Character constant too long for its type, what's wrong?

Tags: c

Why I'm getting this, is the `getchar()` function?

```
printf("Type stop to end connection");
    while ((d=getchar()) != '\n' && i < MAXLENGHT){
    buf2[i++] = d;
}
buf2[i] = '\0';
dfg = strlen(buf2);}
while (d != 'stop'); // here the error
close(sockfd);
exit(0);
```

}

Comment: show us declaration of variables and the constant...

Answer (score 4):

The single quote marks denote a `char` literal. Usually that means a single character. Multi-character literals are permitted, but the standard says that their meaning is implementation defined. It would seem that your implementation regards `'stop'` as being invalid due to having too many characters.

In any case, I'm fairly sure you were not intending to write a multi-character literal. Looking at the snippet of code I think you mean to read the input into a string and use `strcmp` to test for equality with the string `"stop"`.

Comment: `'stop'` is not necessarily invalid, multi-character character literals are part of the language (but with implementation-defined semantics). The warning "character constant too long for its type" most likely just means that `sizeof(int) < 4`. (But of course, `strcmp` with `"stop"` is the right thing here.)

Comment: @Daniel I didn't know about multi-character literals until today. Thanks for correcting me. This is the language that just keeps on giving!

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the syntax error ('' instead of ""), you probably wanted to compare strings:

```
while (strcmp(buf2, "stop") != 0) ...
```